# Got an error while using WorkerProcess.GetRequests method from Microsoft.Web.Administration.dll IIS 8.5

Tags: c#, iis, .net-4.5

I'm writing a windows service application in C# (.NET Framework 4.5) for Microsoft Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard x64 (IIS 8.5) and using Microsoft.Web.Administration.dll (7.0.0.0 from C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv).

When I run the following code:

```
using(var srvmngr = new Microsoft.Web.Administration.ServerManager())
{
    foreach(var pl in srvmngr.ApplicationPools)
    {
         foreach (var w3wp in pl.WorkerProcesses)
         {
             foreach (var request in w3wp.GetRequests(0))
             {
                 var success = true;
             }
        }
    }
}
```

The Service starts with administrator privileges and "GetRequests(0)" method raises the following exception:

```
System.NotImplementedException - {"The method or operation is not implemented."}
```

StackTrace:

```
at Microsoft.Web.Administration.Interop.IAppHostMethodInstance.Execute()
at Microsoft.Web.Administration.ConfigurationMethodInstance.Execute()
at Microsoft.Web.Administration.WorkerProcess.GetRequests(Int32 timeElapsedFilter)
```

Got the same exception in PowerShell using the following code:

```
PS > [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("C:\windows\system32\inetsrv\Microsoft.We‌​‌​b.Administration.dll" )
PS > $sm = new-object Microsoft.Web.Administration.ServerManager
PS > $sm.workerprocesses | foreach-object {$_.GetRequests(0)}
```

Can someone advice me?

Comment: Got the same "Not Implemented" exception using the following command:
`%systemroot%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd list requests`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I finally have solved my problem.

Follow the steps below to complete this problem: 
Add Roles and Features Wizard -> Server Roles -> Web Server (IIS) -> Web Server -> Health and Diagnostics -> Request Monitor

Comment: Please accept your answer to indicate to others that it solves your problem.

Comment: In my case, this error started occuring after installing the "Dynamic IP Restrictions" IIS plugin (worked fine previously). Haven't found a solution yet. Obviously Request Monitor is still installed.