# The method or operation is not implemented. while stopping IIS website in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, server

So Let me tell you that I am developing a **IIS monitoring Website** in MVC 5

I try to stop an application within C# code but it always throw exception. mentioned in the title.

I am using code:

```
ServerManager manager = new ServerManager(@"C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config");

foreach (Site site in manager.Sites)
{
    site.Stop();
}
```

The exception is:

```
{"The method or operation is not implemented."}
   at Microsoft.Web.Administration.Interop.IAppHostMethodInstance.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Web.Administration.ConfigurationMethodInstance.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Web.Administration.ConfigurationElement.ExecuteMethod(String methodName)
   at Microsoft.Web.Administration.Site.Stop()
   at WebsiteReplication.Repository.IISConfiguration.VerifyWebsites(List`1 websitesDirs) in e:\RLTSquare\MetisSilverlight\Code\WebsiteReplication\WebsiteReplication\Repository\IISConfiguration.cs:line 67
```

What I have read uptil now that I need to run my website under administrator privilages. I did that also, I also tried to add manifest file and than changing the access level by this line of code

```
<requestedExecutionLevel  level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
```

Nothing is not working. As I cannot add this manifest file to MVC application because the combobox under properties of the project does not show menifest file there.

**I want to list all websites from IIS server in my MVC application. Also I need to stop/start website from my MVC application.**

Comment: Did you check this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19181418/got-an-error-while-using-workerprocess-getrequests-method-from-microsoft-web-adm

Comment: The problem occurs on my local machine IIS, since I am in developement stages.
Can you please tell me where can I find the path 

 Roles and Features Wizard -> Server Roles -> Web Server (IIS) -> Web Server -> Health and Diagnostics -> Request Monitor

Comment: So everything is all working ?:)

Comment: still stuck. Where can i find: Roles and feature wizard on my local machine?

Comment: Which version of `Microsoft.Web.Administration` are you using?

Comment: I installed latest from nuget. Its 10.x. I gave absolute path of IIS in ServerManager constructor. Actually it was reading IISExpress websites before.
But the problem was only solved by changing the AppPoolIdentity to Local System

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, after alot of R&D i am able to answer my own question. I just changed the app pool rights from **AppPoolIdentity** to **LocalSystem** and everything was fine.